# ASP.NET MVC pagedlist loose checkboxlist filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, checkboxlist, pagedlist

I'm working on an Asp MVC application that contains a grid of data that I can filter with a checkboxlist.I'm using PagedList to display the data. My filter works well on the first page, but if I click on the 2nd page, the filter is cancelled. I don't have this problem with filter using dropdownlist(it's not in the following example).

My view looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<nav id="sidebar">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decision)
    }
</nav>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                Decision
            </th>

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.OnePageOfMissions)
        {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.decision)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.OnePageOfMissions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, Decision = Model.Decision}))
    </table>
</div>
```

I created a template to display checkboxlist like this:

```
<div class="form-check row">
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input col-md-2" })
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Display, Model.Display, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-check-label col-md-8" })
```

My controller looks like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? page, List<CheckBoxListItem> Decision)
    {
        IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
        //Display Missions
        model.missionsList = db.missions_supportmission.ToList();
        //Retrieve parameters    
        model.Decision = Decision;
        //PagedList
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10); // will only contain 10 products max because of the pageSize(equel to 10)
        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;
         //Filter
        if (model.Decision != null)
        {
            var selecteddecision = model.Decision.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID);
            model.OnePageOfMissions = (from m in db.missions_supportmission
                                       join l in db.list_decision
                                       on m.decision equals l.decision_id
                                       where selecteddecision.Contains(l.decision_id)
                                       select m)
                                      .OrderBy(a => a.id)
                                      .ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
        }
            }
        }
        //Display CheckBox
        //Checkboxlist (!important => mettre ce bloc de code après la requête link qui permet de filtrer sur les checkbox)
        var allDecisions = db.list_decision.ToList();//returns List<list_decision>
        var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>(); //nouvelle instance de la classe checkboxlist
        model.Decision = checkBoxListItems;
        foreach (var decison in allDecisions)
        {//On assigne les valeurs "id", "display" et "is checked" à la variable checkboxlistitem
            checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
            {
                ID = decison.decision_id,
                Display = decison.name_en,
                IsChecked = false //On the add view, no decision are selected by default
            });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I have also a ViewModel:

```
namespace MissionsDF.Models
{
public class IndexViewModel
{

    public IEnumerable<missions_supportmission> missionsList { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxListItem> Decision { get; set; }
    public IndexViewModel()
    {
        this.Decision = new List<CheckBoxListItem>();
    }
    public IPagedList<missions_supportmission> OnePageOfMissions { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a collection of complex objects in a url using `new { Decision = Model.Decision}` (look at the url it is generating) - you need to pass each property of each item in the collection to make it bind - but that would make no sense because you would probably exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. One option would be to have a (say) `string SelectedDecisions` property in the view model containing a comma separated string of the selected ID's, and pass that back in the url, and split it in the POST method.

Comment: I don't see how to do have a property containing a comma separated string of the selected ID's. Can you illustrate your idea?

Comment: Add that property to your view model (and set its value using `if(Decision != null){ var selected = Decision.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID); model.SelectedDecisions = String.Join(",", selected); } else { model.SelectedDecisions = selectedDecisions; }`, then add a `string selectedDecisions` parameter to your model and in the view use `@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.OnePageOfMissions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, selectedDecisions = Model.SelectedDecisions})`.

Comment: If you post the form, `Decision` will have a value, otherwise if you click a page number, then `selectedDecisions` will have the value. But your `new { onchange = "form.submit();` in the `CheckBoxFor()` is terrible practice (and means the user can only ever click one checkbox) - you should allow the user to make their selections and then click a submit button

Comment: You will also need to modify the `if (model.Decision != null)` code so that if it is `null` (i.e. user selected a page number), then you would use `String.Split(...)` to set your `var selecteddecision` variable

Comment: thank you, I will try. Can you detail the script `String.Split(...)`

Comment: `var selecteddecision = model.SelectedDecisions.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x));`

Comment: Thank you it works!! I've just a remark. I don't have problem if I let  new { onchange = "form.submit();}. i tried both : using a button and with the property onchange, I have the same results. Otherwise , I've still something to add in my script. When I change page, the checkbox appear empty;